# script of reading one type of files in multiple directory

Tags: bash, scripts, wc

I have the Directory like `2018-01-10`, `2018-02,10` and so on. In each directory it contains `.CUD` and `.CUR` files. I want the number of data (i.e. `wc -l`) which are in `.CUD` files only.

I used following command:

```
for D in /; do
  wc -l ${D}/ > ${D%/}Request
done
```

It worked fine but the result i'm getting is for all the files which are in the directory. I need the results for `.CUD` files only.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find`,`man xargs` and use something like

```
find . -type f -name '*.CUD' -print0 | xargs -0 -r wc -l
```

Comment: THIS WILL NOT WORK BECAUSE THERE ARE MULTILPLE DIRECTORY FROM WHICH I HAVE TO RETRIEVE DATA .

Comment: @user893815 - What happened when you execute the above command?

Comment: If you read `man find` you'll see that you can replace the `.` (the current directory) with a list of directories for `find` to start searching. Also, DON'T SHOUT.

Comment: waltinator if you don't understand the situation . DON'T COMMENT